# Import data from Microsoft SQL Server to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

I am trying to import data from SQL Server into Excel. I know how to import a table from SQL Server to Excel. What I don't know is, how can I input a condition so SQL Server (or Excel?) understands that I want to import only the data that has a condition (i.e. create a where-clause in T-SQL).

For example: I know how to import `select * from table1`, but I want know how to import `select * from table1 where condition = XXX`.

What makes this a bit difficult is that I need the condition to be linked to an Excel cell. I will have to put in a value in an excel cell (let us say A1) and I want the query to be able to read the value from the cell A1 as a condition in this case. Is that possible?

Preferably, I want to import data from SQL Server to a certain cell in Excel. I have to write a SQL query that return ONE output and put that in an cell in Excel. Is that possible?

I don't know where to write or insert this T-SQL query.

Comment: Do you mean export - SQL to Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want.  Just change the obvious object names/reference.

```
Sub ImportFromSQLServer()

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

Server_Name = "your_server_name"
Database_Name = "Northwind"
'User_ID = "******"
'Password = "****"

SQLStr = "select * from dbo.TBL where ID = '1'" 'and PostingDate = '2020-01-01'"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";"
'& ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

RS.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset RS
    End With

RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this :) I will try it out for sure

Comment: Please give my answer an up-vote if it answers your question and helps you.

Comment: Alright, I am new here and I think I upvoted it. Let me know if I didnt